Множество слушателей при реализации ползунка
this.pr.onpointerenter = _ => //Наводим курсор, добавляем класс
this.pr.onpointerleave = _ => //Уводим, удаляем класс

//Срабатывает нажатие клавиши, далее отслеживаем перемещение над элементом
this.pr.onpointerdown = 
this.pr.onpointermove  = e => 

Когда кликаем по элементу, фиксирую путем
el.setPointerCapture(e.pointerId);

Что позволяет увести курсор в любой угол страницы и продолжать перемещать ползунок.
Хочу услышать ваше мнение, возможно можно реализовать все это куда проще?
С чем столкнулся. Под ползунком расположены несколько блоков вплотную(на каждом из них повешено по событию клика). Курсором кликать ок, попадаю. А вот при касании 50 на 50, либо на блок ниже, либо на ползунок. Возможно ли это поправить, при условии что ползунок и блоки ниже останутся плотно друг к другу.

Много букаф и всё одна вода, как будто диплом пишете............ Самое простое что надо было сделать - привести нормальный воспроизводимый пример проблемы и спросить, что нужно сделать, чтобы не было плохо..
